# Why does it return the none in python shell

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I am trying to create a program which only allows you to write a certain amount of characters as a prompt while using a text box. When I try to run the program it returns none in the python shell and doesn't complete the function I would like it to. I would like it to write "your prompt has been posted" if there are under ten characters and write "The prompt is too long" if there are over 10 character. Thanks in advance for the help. It is greatly appreciated

```
label = Label(tk, text="Prompt:")
label.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)
text = Text(tk, width=50, height=6, bg="gray")
text.place(relx=0.62, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)

def diary():
    print("Why does this not work")

def begin():
    while True:
        answer = input(text.insert(INSERT, diary))
        if len(answer) <= 10:
           print("Your prompt has been posted")
        else:
           print("The prompt is too long")


button = Button(tk, text="Submit", command=begin)
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
```

Comment: The code to create the button that calls `begin` is inside the `begin` function. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean? Could you help us figure it out

Comment: @Barmar The button is separate.

Comment: Look at your indentation, you have the `button =` assignment inside the `while True:` loop in the function.

Comment: @Barmar that is an editing mistake, on our code we have it written differently. We have the button outside the def.

Comment: Don't just tell me, edit the question to show it correctly.

Comment: @Barmar         That is the new edited code. It still shows the error

Comment: @Barmar         We just did. Sorry for the confusion. We are new to this

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?  `input(text.insert(INSERT, diary))`

Answer (score 1):

The code never ends because you told it to run a loop forever without changing anything that would cause it to stop.

Also, whatever you think this code is doing, it's probably not doing it. I count at least three things wrong with this one line of code:

```
answer = input(text.insert(INSERT, diary))
```

The `input` command will read in put from the command line (technically, stdin), which is not something you typically do in a GUI. You are passing it the result of a call to `text.insert`, but `text.insert` isn't documented to return anything. Plus, you're giving `text.insert` a function where it expects a string.

If you want to insert what the function `diary` returns, you must a) define `diary` to do something, and b) *call* it as a function. For example:

```
def diary():
    return "something"
...
text.insert(INSERT, diary())
```

If your real goal is to have `begin` get what the user has entered in the GUI and check the length, then you need to remove the while loop and replace the call to `insert` with `get`:

```
def begin():
    answer = text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    if len(answer) <= 10:
       print("Your prompt has been posted")
    else:
       print("The prompt is too long")
```

Comment: We got it to work. Thanks so much for the help. We really appreciate it.